# How to add accessToken authentication in Zuul API Gateway?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, netflix-zuul

I would like to authenticate all the requests at Zuul Gateway. i,e., each API request will send accessToken and zuul should authenticate the accessToken.

I have implemented this by extending ZuulFilter.
My code is below:

```java
@Component
public class ZuulPreFilter extends ZuulFilter {
    @Autowired
    private DiscoveryClient discoveryClient;

    @Override
    public String filterType() {
        return PRE_TYPE;
    }

    @Override
    public int filterOrder() {
        return PRE_DECORATION_FILTER_ORDER + 1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldFilter() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Object run() {
        RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();

        HttpServletRequest request = ctx.getRequest();

        String accessToken = request.getParameter("accessToken");

        if (accessToken == null || accessToken.isEmpty()) {
            return sendUnauthorizedResponse(ctx, request, "Required AccessToken");
        }

        List<ServiceInstance> instances = this.discoveryClient.getInstances("security_service");

        if (instances != null && instances.size() > 0) {
            ServiceInstance securityService = instances.get(0);
            String authAccessTokenAPI = securityService.getUri().toString().concat("/users/?accessToken=")
                    .concat(accessToken);
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            ResponseEntity<ValidationResponse> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(authAccessTokenAPI,
                    ValidationResponse.class);
            ValidationResponse authUserResponse = response.getBody();
            if (authUserResponse == null || !authUserResponse.isSuccess()) {
                return sendUnauthorizedResponse(ctx, request, "Invalid AccessToken");
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
    
    private Object sendUnauthorizedResponse(RequestContext ctx, HttpServletRequest request, String responseMessage) {
        ctx.setSendZuulResponse(false);
        ctx.setResponseStatusCode(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value());
        ValidationResponse validationResponse = new ValidationResponse();
        validationResponse.setSuccess(false);
        validationResponse.setMessage(responseMessage);

        String contentType = request.getContentType();
        if (contentType == null) {
            contentType = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON;
        }

        // To handle Json contentType
        if (contentType.equalsIgnoreCase(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)) {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            try {
                String responseBody = mapper.writeValueAsString(validationResponse);
                ctx.setResponseBody(responseBody);
                ctx.getResponse().setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
            } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {

            }
        }
        
        // To handle XML contentType
        if (contentType.equalsIgnoreCase(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)) {
            String responseBody = XmlUtil.marshal(validationResponse);
            ctx.setResponseBody(responseBody);
            ctx.getResponse().setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
        }

        return ctx;
    }
}
```

I felt its NOT an effective way. Is there any other way to implement this scenario ?
Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app-gateway/blob/master/src/main/java/io/github/jhipster/sample/gateway/accesscontrol/AccessControlFilter.java

Comment: Can you explain, why you think it is not effective?